# Using JSON to store template driven form data in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I need to use JSON to store the form data, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I know I need to store all of the data that is gathered from text fields and radio buttons and then I need to make a form that displays the data. Can anyone point me to good resources for this? Or know how I can do this? I also need to know how I can access the data for another page since this is an application with two pages. One is for gathering data and the other is for displaying.

Comment: pls take a look at this, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-survey-creation-xgjnhl is it the one u looking for?

Comment: I can't tell where the code for converting the data into JSON is. From what I can tell, it looks like it might help me, but I don't see where JSON is used besides the one file.

Comment: see `postSurvey()` at `create-survey.component.ts`

Comment: so that method converts the data into JSON? I wasn't sure because I thought there had to be something like `JSON.stringify(data)`. Does it store it in a JSON file?

Comment: i'll create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically to store form datas to JSON is simply create a JSON object and assign the form value to specified property inside that object.

my method is simple like this, on submit i add new object

```
let newValue = {
     inputValue : this.form.value.input,
     selectValue : this.form.value.select,
    }
```

thats just for an example, assignin form value to the property of our new object. then to push the data to api simply like this

```
pushToAPIFunc(newValue);
```

and the result will be like this

```
{
  "newValue" :{
      "inputValue" : "inputValue",
      "selectValue" : "selectValue"
   }
}
```

to display that data, for example u have an edit page, u can use `patchValue()` of that JSON to your form, or assigning that data manually to each `formControlName`

Comment: Okay yeah that helps a lot. Thank you.